# How do I use a DOCTYPE that validate?

Tags: html, doctype

I am trying to troubleshoot some issues on a website that is going live today and I keep getting this funny error in Firebug and on the W3C validation site

Here is my DOCTYPE code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Here is the error I get:

> syntax error
>   [Break On This Error] < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHT.../xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Any guidance on this seemingly simple task would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did some `&#8220;`s sneak in there instead of straight double quotes? What's the character encoding of the document? Is there any white space or text output before your `DOCTYPE` declaration?

Comment: I really don't want to invest time in building a test case to see if I'm interpreting your error messages correctly (hint: **Provide a working test case!**), but that looks like Firefox is getting a 404 error page for a `<script src>` URI but not with a 404 status code, so it is trying to treat an HTML document as JS. That has nothing to do with validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have the same problem here:
http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/09/06/syntax-error-break-on-this-error-doctype-html-public-w3cdtd-xhtml3orgtr-xhtml1-dtd-xhtml1-strictdtd/

check your script tags!

the following gives the same result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whitespace is allowed before the Doctype (as are comments, XML declarations and (IIRC) PIs).

Comment: He has `transitional`, not `strict` doctype.

Comment: voted up for pointing to a thread where solution was available (in comments, though). I suggest the people should start reading comments too instead where solutions may be available. Solution was to remove reference to a non-existing location/file.